# Angular archive/gh-14284

Tags: angularjs

BlackDuck scan reports a vulnerability with AngularJS 1.8.2 version.

Recommendation shown to address the vulnerabilty - was to upgrade to Angular archive/gh-14284

I was not able to find any info regarding archive/gh-14284

Any help or information regarding source or usage of Angular archive/gh-14284 will be very helpful.